# react-native-fbsdk Unable to share videos

Tags: react-native

```
const shareContent = {
    contentType: 'video',
    video: {
        localUrl: 'response.uri'
    },
};
ShareDialog.show(shareContent)
```

报错：ShareDialog encounters error

Comment: What error? And can you show your full code? And should your `response.uri` be a string or how are you getting `response.uri`? And do you have publish_action permission on FB?

Comment: Please update your question with more detail, as it stands your question is unclear, and it makes it difficult to help you. Please add your error messages, and relevant code so that it is easier to help you.

Comment: @LordKiz  分享视频到 Facebook 必须要有publish_action权限吗

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, NativeModules, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet} from "react-native";
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
const ShareDialog = NativeModules.FBShareDialog

export default class Facebook extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center',}}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    this.shareLinkWithShareDialog()
                }} style={[styles.avatar, styles.avatarContainer, { marginBottom: 30 }]}>
                    <Text>分享链接</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    this.selectPhotoTapped()
                }} style={[styles.avatar, styles.avatarContainer, { marginBottom: 30 }]}>
                    <Text>分享图片</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    this.selectVideoTapped()
                }} style={[styles.avatar, styles.avatarContainer, { marginBottom: 30 }]}>
                    <Text>分享视频</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }

    // 分享链接
    shareLinkWithShareDialog() {
        const shareContent = {
            contentType: 'link',
            contentUrl: "www.facebook.com",
            quote: "假装是个标题",
        };
        this.shareWithShareDialog(shareContent)
    }


    // 分享图片
    selectPhotoTapped() {
        var photoOptions = {
            //底部弹出框选项
            title: '请选择',
            cancelButtonTitle: '取消',
            takePhotoButtonTitle: '拍照',
            chooseFromLibraryButtonTitle: '选择相册',
            quality: 0.75,
            allowsEditing: true,
            noData: false,
            storageOptions: {
                skipBackup: true,
                path: 'images'
            }
        }

        ImagePicker.showImagePicker(photoOptions, (response) => {
            console.log('Response = ', response);

            if (response.didCancel) {
                console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
            }
            else if (response.error) {
                console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
            }
            else if (response.customButton) {
                console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
            }
            else {
                const shareContent = {
                    contentType: 'photo',
                    photos: [
                        {
                            imageUrl: response.uri,
                            userGenerated: false,
                            caption: "Hello World"
                        }
                    ]
                };
                this.shareWithShareDialog(shareContent)
            }
        });
    }

    // 分享视频
    selectVideoTapped() {
        var videoOptions = {
            title: '选择视频',
            cancelButtonTitle: '取消',
            takePhotoButtonTitle: '录制视频',
            chooseFromLibraryButtonTitle: '选择视频',
            mediaType: 'video',
            videoQuality: 'medium'
        }

        ImagePicker.showImagePicker(videoOptions, (response) => {
            console.log('Response = ', response);

            if (response.didCancel) {
                console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
            }
            else if (response.error) {
                console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
            }
            else if (response.customButton) {
                console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
            }
            else {
                console.log('视频选择成功', response.uri)
                const videoUri = response.uri
                const shareContent = {
                    contentType: 'video',
                    video: {
                        localUrl: videoUri
                    },
                };
                ShareDialog.show(shareContent)
            }
        });
    }

    // 分享结构
    shareWithShareDialog(shareContent: any) {
        ShareDialog.canShow(shareContent).then(
            function (canShow) {
                console.log('canShow = ', canShow)
                if (canShow) { // vedio: canshow = false
                    return ShareDialog.show(shareContent); //  video Error: ShareDialog encounters error
                }
            }
        ).then(
            function (result) {
                if (result.isCancelled) {
                    console.log('Share cancelled');
                } else {
                    console.log('Share success with postId: '
                        + result.postId);
                }
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log('Share fail with error: ' + error);
            }
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
    },
    avatarContainer: {
        borderColor: '#9B9B9B',
        borderWidth: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    avatar: {
        borderRadius: 50,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        marginTop: 30
    }

});
```

这是我的代码，分享链接和照片都OK，分享视频就会报错 ShareDialog encounters error

我不知道是视频路径的问题还是其他什么问题。